# How can i ignore 14 punctuation marks

Tags: c#

I need to find the same words in the string, I split it into words with the split method but I get the error because `berhan` is not the same as `berhan,`. I keep the punctuation marks in a series how can I remove them If a word X (except stop words) appears more than 2 times in the text, the computer asks "Do you love X? Assume that stop words are stored in the following array:

```
string[] stop_words = {″a″, ″after″, ″again, ″all″, ″am″, ″and″, ″any″, ″are″, ″as″, ″at″, ″be″, ″been″, ″before″, ″between″, ″both″, ″but″, ″by″, ″can″, ″could″, ″for″, ″from″, ″had″, ″has″, ″he″, ″her″, ″here″, ″him″, ″in″, ″into″, ”I”, ″is″, ″it″, ″me″, ″my″, ″of″, ″on″, ″our″, ″she″, ″so″, ″such″, ″than″, ″that″, ″the″, ″then″, ″they″, ″this″, ″to″, ″until″, ″we″, ″was″, ″were″, ″with″, ″you″}
```

For Example input:

> hello, i have a guitar, and my guitar is blue output: Do you love guitar

i use split method but "guitar," is not equal "guitar"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include your code, and show where you're having your challenges. And also please show some sample input data (and expected / actual output).  Without code, and without anything showing example strings you're parsing, it's really difficult to attempt to answer such a question.

Comment: For Example 
input : hello, i have a guitar, and my guitar is blue
output: Do you love guitar
i use split method but "guitar," is not equal "guitar"

Comment: Ok, great - please *edit your question* though - it is pretty difficult to read code as unformatted text in a comment. Also, great you shared some input data, as well as how you plan on using it. Please also share code you've written, and where you're stuck. You mentioned having split into words; it would be super helpful to show that. Otherwise, this reads as "please write code for me" (which is off-topic).

Comment: You just want to remove the punctuation from the string? This could be done with [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *extracting* words instead of *splitting* (when you have as many as **14** punctuation marks already there's a possibility that there's a **15th** one, say `՜` - `U+055C` *Armenian Exclamation Mark*); try using *regular expressions* for this:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string source = @"A lot of words: there're some Russian ones (русские слова).";

  string[] words = Regex
    .Matches(source, @"[\p{L}']+") // word is composed from letters and apostrophes
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words));
```

Outcome:

```
A
lot
of
words
there're
some
Russian
ones
русские
слова
```

If you want to find out the *same* (repeated) words, add *grouping* (`GroupBy`) in order to get rid of stop words - *filtering* (`Where`):

```
  HashSet<string> stopWords = 
    new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) {
      "is", "a", //TODO: put stopwords here 
  };

  string[] repeatedWords = Regex
    .Matches(source, @"[\p{L}']+") // word is composed from letters and apostrophes
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .Where(word => !stopWords.Contains(word)) // not a stopword
    .GroupBy(word => word, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 2) // appeared more than 2 times
    .Select(group => group.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

**Edit:** How many punctuation mark do we actually have?

```
  int count = Enumerable
    .Range(0, char.MaxValue)
    .Count(c => char.IsPunctuation((char)c));

  Console.Write(count);
```

It may surprise you, but as many as **593** (not even close to **14**)